# Missing debugging symbols in pthread library 

Tags: multithreading

I am trying to debug (using gdb) a multi-threaded program, which 
uses POSIX threads.

I am getting message like :

```
Reading symbols from /lib/libpthread.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

looks like the library is not compiled with -g option.

Where can I find this library ? I tried to find it 
on web but I am not getting proper answers ...

Please help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all, unless you actually want to step inside pthread functions–or any other library–you won't need the debugging information for that library.  You can still debug the main application without getting yourself into the libraries.

If you think there's a problem with a library, take a deep breath and look at your code again.  Most common libraries (like pthread) have pretty solid code.  If you still want to peer inside pthread_cond_wait(), look for a package for your library that looks something like "*[pkg]*-debuginfo".  It should have what you want.

Comment: In debian-based distros the packages with debugging symbols are called `*-dbg`. (Not that I think you actually need to debug pthread either.)

Answer (score 1):

if you are unable to find dbg libraries in your system, you can look at the required package debug version [installing](https://askubuntu.com/a/1912/20972) and using
`apt-file find 'library name' | grep dbg` 
and install the one required for your system.

Answer (score 0):

In my application, I did need the libpthread.so debug symbols to have the entire backtrace when my application freezes in a mutex.
Without the symbols I have this error :

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000007f7f930690 in __lll_lock_wait () from /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
#1  0x0000007f7f9297d8 in pthread_mutex_lock () from /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)
```

I used the following commands to install libpthread.so debug symbols in **Ubuntu 18.04**.

```
echo "deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs) main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs)-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://ddebs.ubuntu.com $(lsb_release -cs)-proposed main restricted universe multiverse" | \
tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ddebs.list
apt install ubuntu-dbgsym-keyring
apt update
apt install libc6-dbg
```